# Does being on a tile where a boat comes to shore put my soldiers at a disadvantage?

Tags: bad-north

When enemy boats come to shore, they "bump" into my soldiers, and they slightly scatter — is this purely visual, or does being there actually put my soldiers at a disadvantage? How complex are the mechanics in this scenario?

Would it be a better tactic to wait for the "bump" before moving my soldiers to that tile?
Does the fact that enemy soldiers are disembarking put 'em at a disadvantage, 'cause they aren't in formation yet?

Answer (score 2):

The bump *does* affect them. The boat stuns the troops for a moment and the attackers sometimes get in a few free hits.

Comment: so it might be a good idea to have soldiers on the landing tile if the boat is full of archers, but prolly not if it has any other type of enemy, I assume....?